# how to stop Matlab figure from maximizing?

Tags: matlab, figure

I want to disable the Maximize option of Matlab figure. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [figure property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html) you need to change for that:

```
set(fHandle,'Resize','off');
```

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB File Exchange has [WindowAPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi), which does exactly what you're looking for.

You can crop the complete window border by:

```
WindowAPI(gcf, 'Clip', true);
```